# Appending Excel files to Python DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, append

The below code goes through the excel files in the Regis folder and appends them into a new DataFrame. I need to make the following changes to the code:

1. The data starts in column 7 so I do not need to append the first 6 rows of each Excel file
2. Each Excel Sheet has a date at the end of the file name e.g. "Regis 30012022" The last 8 digits are the date (European format) and I would like to add a column so that I know which date the data refers to. This date should be added to column A.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
  
# path of the folder
path = r'Regis'

# reading excel files
filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
print('File names:', filenames)
  
# initializing empty data frame
finalexcelsheet = pd.DataFrame()
  
# interating through all excel files
for file in filenames:
  
    # combining multiple excel worksheets into single data frames
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True, sort=False)
  
    # appending excel files one by one
    finalexcelsheet = finalexcelsheet.append(df, ignore_index=True)
  
finalexcelsheet.to_excel(r'Final.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first point, you can add the argument `skiprows` into your reading of the file:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, skiprows = 6), ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

For the second issue, I would do the following:

```
for file in filenames:
  
    temp_df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=6)
    date_string = "".join(character for character in file if character.isdigit())
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d%M%Y")
    temp_df["date"]= date

    df = pd.concat(temp_df, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
  
    # appending excel files one by one
    finalexcelsheet = finalexcelsheet.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

This is reading in the excel file, creating a datetime object from the filename, and using that datetime object to create a new column for `temp_df` before using concat.